# Send PL/SQL to Oracle without creating a stored procedure

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jdbc, plsql

I am a total newbie in PL/SQL Oracle. I am used to work with JDBC framework and standard SQL.

For example, the next PL/SQL:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Column1=’SomeValue’)
    UPDATE Table1 SET (…) WHERE Column1=’SomeValue’
ELSE
    INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (…)
```

This sentence has to be executed from a stored procedure in oracle so you have to create a procedure in database and call it but why is the reason I cannot send this sentence to the database like a "select" statement and being executed without having to create a stored procedure first?

Comment: you don't really need PL/SQL for this, you can use `MERGE`. Or use an anonymous PL/SQL block. No stored procedure required.

Comment: I know, thanks. What I meant is why I cannot send a pl/sql to the database like a select sentence.

Comment: Because you are asking it to execute an incomplete PL/SQL block. At a minimum, you need to convert it into a valid anonymous PL/SQL block: `begin <insert_pl_sql_code_here> end;`

Comment: You don't show us your actual code, so we can't say why it fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can execute an anonymous PL/SQL block with a callable statement. You'll want to use a prepared statement as it increases performance in Oracle and prevents SQL injections.

The PL/SQL block is nested with BEGIN and END, or if you have local variables, with DECLARE / BEGIN / END.

```
String plsqlBlock =
    "begin " +
    "  update Table1 " +
    "    set val1 = :v1, val2 = :v2 " +
    "    where primary_key = :pk; " +
    "  if sql%rowcount = 0 then " +
    "    insert into Table1 (primary_key, val1, val2) " +
    "      values (:pk, :v1, :v2); " +
    "  end if; " +
    "end;";

CallableStatement cs = connection.prepareCall(plsqlBlock);
cs.setInt("pk", 12345);
cs.setString("v1", "abc");
cs.setString("v2", "def");
cs.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are allowed to execute PL/SQL directly to the database using a client, and embed your code in a "`begin ... end`" structure.

e.g. using [`sqlplus`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlplus) This would look like the below (never forget to end the plsql statements with a `/` - last line / first char):

```
begin
  IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Column1=’SomeValue’) 
  THEN
    UPDATE Table1 SET (…) WHERE Column1=’SomeValue’
    ;
  ELSE
    INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (…) 
    ;
  END IF;
end;
/
```

(I added the correct syntax for your `if / else` structure)

Comment: The `if exists (implicit cursor)` construction from the OP isn't actually PL/SQL. Probably there is some other language he was thinking of.